# Backup/Restore LibreOffice Default Styles and Theme

Tags: backup, themes, libreoffice

I have customized a local installation of LibreOffice with default styles, customized toolbar, theme.  How can I reliably backup all these settings and propagate to other PCs (say all Ubuntu installations on the same campus)?  All target PCs have the same Ubuntu version and the same LibreOffice version as the source machine.  Preferably, all operations to be performed via command line so that the operation can be automated and unattended.

Things I have done and tried:

I looked for clues in the documentation: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile.

Looked for relevant paths in **Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths** and found `$HOME/.config/libreoffice` and `/usr/lib/libreoffice` and attempted the following three file transfers that did not work as intended (the third one is dangerous as it replaces binaries on the target machine).

On the source machine:

```
cd $HOME
tar jcvf - $HOME/.config/libreoffice > libreoffice_user_settings.tar.bz2
tar jcvf - /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config  > libreoffice_lib_config.tar.bz2
tar jcvf - /usr/lib/libreoffice  > libreoffice_lib_full.tar.bz2
```

On a target machine:

```
rsync -avz SOURCE:libreoffice_*.tar.bz2 .
tar xvjf libreoffice_user_settings.tar.bz2
tar xvjf libreoffice_lib_config.tar.bz2
tar xvjf libreoffice_lib_full.tar.bz2
```

After each of the untarring I started LibreOffice on the target machine, only to find out that the old styles and theme still prevailed.

**UPDATE:** I found that the `tar xvjf` created new subdirectories in $HOME instead of untarring in place.  This is a **partial solution**:

```
cd /
tar xvjf $HOME/libreoffice_user_settings.tar.bz2
```

Now for the second part of my question: propagate that to other PCs (i.e. making the settings machine-wide and not user-specific).  I suspect this will require copying the settings (or some of them) to `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config`

I also looked at `/etc/libreoffice/sofficerc` but there was nothing relevant there.

Comment: Does copying `~/.config/libreoffice` to another machine help?

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried and did not help.